# How to test if a condition, when it's the right class but empty

Tags: r

Sometimes, I find myself in a situation where something returns TRUE to `is.numeric` but the real result is `numeric(0)`. So it's not actually a number. How would I test if it's ACTUALLY numeric and not just an empty numeric.

Here's a bogus example:

```
x <- as.numeric(factor())
[1] numeric(0)
```

How do I test if x is more than just the class "numeric", as in an actual number?

PS: For those of you wondering how I could end up in such an odd situation, I'm scraping the web and looking to convert a number that isn't always in the same place. So sometimes, I'm essentially calling `as.numeric(factor())` which gives `numeric(0)`

Comment: `length(x)` gives 0, in your case.

Comment: `length(x)` will return `0` if it has no content

Comment: Ah, I feel so silly. Someone type that as an answer and get their +1 and check.

Comment: @GaryWeissman Please, do so.

Comment: @Pascal no, you take this one. You beat me by 13 seconds on the post ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `length` for this purpose:

```
x <- as.numeric(factor())
x
# [1] numeric(0)
class(x)
# [1] "numeric"
length(x)
# [1] 0
```

Comparison:

```
y <- 1
y
# [1] 1
class(y)
# [1] "numeric"
length(y)
# [1] 1
```